# Make grafana use existing JWT token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, grafana, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a React + DRF web app that has JWT authentication, in which I use djangorestframework-simplejwt.

I store access and refresh tokens in the localStorage. Is it possible to use these tokens to authenticate in Grafana? If yes, how can I do that? When I navigate to /grafana (with nginx help), I would like to see that my user in my app to be logged in to the Grafana, by creating the user for Grafana if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain all of the details for those who seek a solution to the problem of using common JWT for their app and Grafana. You can skip the beginning if you only care about Grafana side only:

**React side:**

- I have a Django REST Framework API and React UI. When a token returned to the user, React UI saves it to the local storage. I implemented an onClick handler for a button to navigate to Grafana like this:

```
// read token value from local storage
const refToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
window.location.href = `/grafana/login/?mytoken=${refToken}`;
```

**Django REST Framework side (djangorestframework-simplejwt):**

- The API can generate and validate JWT tokens using RS256 signing algorithm. Because of the RSA, the API needs to generate 2 keys, private and public key. I have generated those with `jwcrypto`. I set `SIGNING_KEY` with the contents of the private key .pem and set `VERIFYING_KEY` with the contents of the public key .pem.

```
from jwcrypto import jwk
import uuid

keyid = str(uuid.uuid4())
key = jwk.JWK.generate(kty='RSA', alg='RS256', size=2048, kid=keyid, use='sig')

# export to PEM files
priv_pem = key.export_to_pem(private_key=True, password=None)
pub_pem = key.export_to_pem()

with open("rsa_pub.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pub_pem)

with open("rsa.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(priv_pem)
```

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'SIGNING_KEY': open("/path/to/folder/which/has/keys/rsa.pem").read(),
    'VERIFYING_KEY': open("/path/to/folder/which/has/keys/rsa_pub.pem").read(),
    'ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'username',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'username',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
}
```

**Grafana side:**

- **To make sure that this is working, you need to create users with same username for the Grafana.** Otherwise you will get `Invalid JWT` response. [`auto_sign_up` setting is not working for the JWT authentication yet.](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/37040)
- Then I added these configurations for Grafana container. `header_name` can be any string and but you need to use it in nginx side too:

```
version: "3"
services:
  ...
  ...
  grafana:
    image:  grafana/grafana:8.2.2
    volumes:
      - ...
      - "/path/to/folder/which/has/keys:/key_set"
    environment:
      - "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=/grafana/"
      - "GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH=true"
      - "GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLED=true"
      - "GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLE_LOGIN_TOKEN=true"
      - "GF_AUTH_JWT_ENABLED=true"
      - "GF_AUTH_JWT_HEADER_NAME=X-JWT-Assertion"
      - "GF_AUTH_JWT_USERNAME_CLAIM=username"
      - "GF_AUTH_JWT_KEY_FILE=/key_set/rsa_pub.pem"
```

**Nginx side:**

```
location /grafana/ {
    try_files /dev/null @proxy_grafana;
}

location /grafana/login/ {
    try_files /dev/null @proxy_grafana_login;
}

location @proxy_grafana {
    ...
    proxy_pass   http://grafana:3000;
}

location @proxy_grafana_login {
    ...
    proxy_set_header X-JWT-Assertion "${arg_mytoken}";
    proxy_pass   http://grafana:3000;
}
```

Comment: Refresh token is not for authentication. Why you don't use access token?

Comment: Access tokens have a short expiration period, I thought that could be bad after I authenticated to grafana. In the app, I have control over the access token and refresh it when needed.

Comment: That's by design. Access token has short expiration and refresh token is used for access token renewal.

Comment: I know. That is something I want to avoid. I don't want the token expire while browsing grafana. If I choose refresh token for authentication in grafana, then my app and grafana will expire together. At least, that was my aim.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is "JWT authentication" and how JWT was created. I guess it is from Open ID Connect authentication, so then nothing is stopping you to use [Grafana OIDC auth](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/) with the same OIDC identuty provider, to have seamless user single sign on experience.

Comment: It is not OIDC, I guess it is something simpler than that. Should I change the authentication method?